# Compile error in scala template while passing an arraylist: Not found value

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to pass an arraylist to a scala template from a play controller.

In my controller

```
List<Profile> profiles = Profile.findAll();

return ok(contacts.render(profiles));
```

In the template contacts.scala.html

```
@import models.com.contactmanager.Profile
@(profiles: List[Profile])
```

I am getting the error:

```
not found: value profiles [error]
```

for line

```
@(profiles: List[Profile])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Parameter lists of Scala templates you have to use the (a) fully qualified class name or (b) you import them in your Build.scala.

(a)

```
@(profiles: List[models.com.contactmanager.Profile])
```

(b)

```
//Play 2.2
val main = PlayProject(…).settings(
  templatesImport += "models.com.contactmanager.Profile"
)
```

For Play 2.3 the API changed:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTemplates#Import-statements

```
TwirlKeys.templateImports += "models.com.contactmanager.Profile"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. What is strange is that if the class is right inside "models", you do not have to specify the fully qualified name. If I create a "services" package, the compiler won't see classes inside that.

Comment: This is right answer, but i want mention that for play 2.3 behaviour is changed, and `templatesImport +=` should be placed in build.sbt file as `TwirlKeys.templateImports +=`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the import statement has to be below the parameter statement.

Try switching the order of

```
@import models.com.contactmanager.Profile
@(profiles: List[Profile])
```

to

```
@(profiles: List[Profile])
@import models.com.contactmanager.Profile
```

Comment: I switched the order of statements as you had suggested, but I am getting the same compile error.

Comment: I also have a Play-Project with a Scala-Template and at least i get "not found: value ???" when i switch them like you had them. I'm afraid I don't know then. Can you maybe post the full template?